# Regex not returning expected value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a basic regex that should return string after the last backslash `\`.

**Regex :**

```
/([^\\]*$)/
```

Works fine in **[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qG6vI3/3)**.

**Output :**

> random.html

But not in Javascript example bellow :

```js
console.log("C:\fakepath\extra\random.html".match(/([^\\]*$)/));
```

**Output :**

> ["C:akepathextra
>   andom.html", "C:akepathextra
>   andom.html", index: 0, input: "C:akepathextra
>   andom.html"]

Comment: The string `"C:\fakepath\extra\random.html"` in JavaScript doesn’t mean what you think it means. Each backslash starts an escape sequence. You have to escape the backslashes like this: `"C:\\fakepath\\extra\\random.html"`.

Comment: ^ also you might use `/([^\\]+$)/` instead to prevent getting empty matches.

Comment: I suggest closing the question since there is no real issue, just a typo when testing a regex.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with the RegEx, it's with the string itself. In JavaScript strings `\` is used to escape the following character.

The string

```
"C:\fakepath\extra\random.html"
```

is after escaping

```
C:akepathextra
andom.html
```

To use backslash in the string, escape them by preceding backslash.

```
"C:\\fakepath\\extra\\random.html"
```

```js
console.log("C:\\fakepath\\extra\\random.html".match(/[^\\]*$/));
```

---

To get the text after last `\`, use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [`Array#pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

```
"C:\\fakepath\\extra\\random.html".split('\\').pop() // random.html
                                          ^^ Note: this backslash also need to be escaped.
```

Answer (score 1):

`[^\\]*` match a single character not present in the list.

**Quantifier**: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

The problem is not with the RegEx, it's with the string itself. In JavaScript strings `\` is used to escape the following character.
To use backslash in the string then escape them by preceding backslash.

```
"C:\\fakepath\\extra\\random.html"
```