# replace an escaped character, javascript, regexp

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to replace this this str: `'FL\X\KT'` to this `'FLÄKT'`.

Tried this: `str.replace(/\\X\\/g, 'Ä');`

But this just removes the backslashes.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a real [MCVE]. If that example string is supposed to be an actual JavaScript string literal, then the resulting string object won't have any slashes in it in the first place.

Comment: how are you defining the original string? \X and \K aren't string metachars, so the backslashes may be parsed away, leaving just `FLXKT` in the string, meaning you have to do `var foo = 'FL\\X\\KT'` to end up with `FL\X\KT` in the string.

Comment: 4 backslashes will do it

Comment: _But this just removes the backslashes._ **No**. There are no backslashes in the original string. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943875/regex-not-returning-expected-value) post.

Comment: `str.replace(/X/g, 'Ä');` .... the backslash doesn't have any effect in your string `'FL\X\KT'=='FLXKT'`

Answer (score 1):

```
str ='FL\\X\\KT';
str.replace(/\\X\\/g, 'Ä');
```

One more example to illustrate this more clearly, you can use alert instead of console.log if you want:

```
<div id="a">FL\X\KT</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var a='FL\\X\\KT';
    console.log(a);
    console.log(document.getElementById('a').innerHTML=='FL\\X\\KT');
</script>
```

Comment: You must escape backslashes in string.

Comment: OP wants to transform *that specific string*... Your answer could be: `str ='FLÄKT';
str.replace(/ /, ' ');` :-(

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is treated as a escape character, so you can use just:

```
str = str.replace(/X/g, 'Ä');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fk9e3x86/)

This will work on simple string where you want to replace `X` wit `Ä`. However if you have more imput, also containing `X` which you don't want to replace, I think you can try with something like:

```
var str = unescape("FL\\X\\KT");
str = str.replace(/\\X\\/g, 'Ä');
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4LmbsLpg/)

however the unescape function is deprecated, so it is not the best idea.